# Can I relicense an Apache- or -MIT-licensed software to AGPL (Affero General Public License)?

Tags: mit, apache-2.0, agpl

Apache 2.0 is compatible with GPL 3.0, but how about AGPL? Can I relicense any Apache or MIT licensed software to AGPL?

Answer (score 3):

To my understanding, all licenses that are compatible with GPLv3 are also compatible with LGPLv3 and AGPLv3.

In fact, if you compare the license texts of [GPLv3](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html) and [AGPLv3](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.en.html), apart from the Preamble, the rest of the license texts are virtually exactly the same, except Section 13. I say "virtually" because of the obvious differences of the names of the licenses, of course.

Section 13 of GPLv3 and AGPLv3 license texts make them compatible with each other for linking, while adding the Remote Network Interaction clause to the AGPLv3.

Hence, the Apache License v2.0 is [compatible](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html#apache2) with the AGPLv3.

However, please note that you can relicense a work based on [Apache License v2.0](https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0) only when you create a Derivative Work out of it. The original Work would have to be distributed under the original license.

This is based on Section 4 of the Apache License v2.0:

> You may add Your own copyright statement to Your modifications and may
> provide additional or different license terms and conditions for use,
> reproduction, or distribution of Your modifications, or for any such
> Derivative Works as a whole, provided Your use, reproduction, and
> distribution of the Work otherwise complies with the conditions stated
> in this License.

Comment: Do Apache and AGPL manage configuration files? Configuration files may include user preferences or program settings, which are unlikely to be qualified as source code.

Comment: @Flan1335 If the configuration file was generated by your software, then no, they are not subject to the license. If the configuration file is part of your source code repo, then you may license it however way you like. If no explicit license is specified, then the overall license applies to the configuration files (in the repo) too. Please see "[In what cases is the output of a GPL program covered by the GPL too?](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html#WhatCaseIsOutputGPL)".

Comment: Apache requires a copyright notice if someone else modified the source code. If I modified the source code, then immediately relicense it under GPL, LGPL, or AGPL, does it need a copyright notice for the derivative work?